# Pandas dataframe split array entry into two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
       reviewerID        asin    reviewerName helpful  unixReviewTime  \
0  A1N4O8VOJZTDVB  B004A9SDD8  Annette Yancey  [1, 1]      1383350400
```

I'd like to split the 'helpful' column into two different columns with names 'helpful_numerator' and 'helpful denominator and I can't figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to unzip `helpful` into separate columns:

```
df['helpful_numerator'], df['helpful_denominator'] = zip(*df['helpful'])
```

**Edit**

As mentioned by @MaxU in the comments, if you want to drop the `helpful` column from your DataFrame, use [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) when selecting the column in `zip`:

```
df['helpful_numerator'], df['helpful_denominator'] = zip(*df.pop('helpful'))
```

**Timings**

Using the following setup to create a larger sample DataFrame and functions to time against:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abc'), 'B': [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]})
df = pd.concat([df]*10**5, ignore_index=True)

def root(df):
    df['C'], df['D'] = zip(*df['B'])
    return df

def maxu(df):
    return df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('B').tolist(), columns=['C', 'D']))

def flyingmeatball(df):
    df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
    df['D'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
    return df

def psidom(df):
    df['C'] = df.B.str[0]
    df['D'] = df.B.str[1]
    return df
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit root(df.copy())
10 loops, best of 3: 70.6 ms per loop

%timeit maxu(df.copy())
10 loops, best of 3: 151 ms per loop

%timeit flyingmeatball(df.copy())
1 loop, best of 3: 223 ms per loop

%timeit psidom(df.copy())
1 loop, best of 3: 283 ms per loop
```

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: Nice I like this!

Comment: What does the '*' do in this solution?

Comment: i'd change: `zip(*df['helpful'])` --> `zip(*df.pop('helpful'))` if OP doesn't need original `helpful` column after splitting

Comment: @root so nice. Any idea of the performance of that neat approach compared to the usual ones we see like in the other answers?

Comment: @tlanigan: The `*` is used for unzipping.  I've added a link to the documentation in my answer, which addresses unzipping at the end.

Comment: @MaxU: Thanks, added the `pop` approach to the answer.

Comment: @Boud: I just did some quick timings, and `zip` appears to be faster.  I'll add the timings shortly.

Answer (score 3):

If `helpful` is a column of lists, you can use `str` to access the element in the list:

```
df['helpful_numerator'] = df.helpful.str[0]    
df['helpful_denominator'] = df.helpful.str[1]
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

yet another solution:

```
In [74]: df
Out[74]:
       reviewerID        asin    reviewerName  unixReviewTime helpful
0  A1N4O8VOJZTDVB  B004A9SDD8  Annette Yancey      1383350400  [1, 1]

In [75]: df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('helpful').tolist(),
                              columns=['helpful_numerator','helpful_denominator']))
Out[75]:
       reviewerID        asin    reviewerName  unixReviewTime  helpful_numerator  helpful_denominator
0  A1N4O8VOJZTDVB  B004A9SDD8  Annette Yancey      1383350400                  1                    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column contains a list, you can use .apply

```
df['helpful_numerator'] = df['helpful'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['helpful_denominator'] = df['helpful'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```